# Microsoft Graph works with one program, but not another

Tags: authentication, graph

I am attempting to create a c# Windows service that periodically captures information from Microsoft Graph.  This always fails with a "AADSTS700016: Application not found in the directory of our Microsoft 365 account."

Prior to trying to write this service, I created a test program to do same access.  I set up an application in Azure Active Directory with a secret.  When I run the exact same code in the this test program with the correct tenant ID, client ID and the secret, the program works fine from whatever computer I run it from.

However, the c# service always fails with the error noted above and detailed below. Can't be an issue with permissions as access IDs and secret are the same.  I have even tried creating a separate application in AAD but get the same error.

Common c# statements:

```
            var scopes = new[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" };

            // Multi-tenant apps can use "common",
            // single-tenant apps must use the tenant ID from the Azure portal
            // using Azure.Identity;
            var options = new TokenCredentialOptions
            {
                AuthorityHost = AzureAuthorityHosts.AzurePublicCloud
            };

            var clientSecretCredential = new ClientSecretCredential(
                tenantId, clientID, clientSecret, options); ;

            graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(clientSecretCredential, scopes);
            if (graphClient == null) throw new Exception("Unable able to obtain a GraphClient for this pass");

            var groups = await graphClient.Groups.Request().Select(x => new { x.Id, x.DisplayName }).GetAsync();
```

Any help appreciated.  I am sure it is something simple, but clueless at the moment.

Inner Exception 1:
AuthenticationFailedException: ClientSecretCredential authentication failed: AADSTS700016: Application with identifier 'c62d4eb9-587d-4b7f-a4d8-0640747f0958' was not found in the directory xxxx. This can happen if the application has not been installed by the administrator of the tenant or consented to by any user in the tenant. You may have sent your authentication request to the wrong tenant.
Trace ID: c8bfac15-c9d6-407e-89e7-36f21fb18300
Correlation ID: 9c8d25ad-c275-43c0-93c1-d295608e9f92
Timestamp: 2022-08-13 15:52:36Z

Answer (score 1):

And just like that, I found the error.  Good old global vs local variable name.  I hope no one spent too much time on this.